# JPA/Hibernate duplicate records

Tags: hibernate, jpa, duplicates

I have a One-to-Many relationship between entities. When doing this JPQL query:

SELECT parent FROM Parent parent JOIN parent.child child WHERE ...

I get duplicate records when a parent has 2 children, only one when a parent have one child, none when there is no child (none when no child is fine). Note that there is no duplicate of Parent in the SQL database.

The entities are declared as follow:

```
@Entity(...)
public class Parent {

    @Id
    Long parentId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentID")
    List<Child> children;
}

@Entity(...)
public class Child {a

    Long parentId;
}
```

I omitted a lot of code for brevity's sake, but that should give you a strong idea of what I am trying to do. Note that the relationship is defined on the parent's side because I need the list of parents along with their children returned from the query.

Comment: It would be nice if you add a question at the end of your post by editing your post

Comment: How do you persist? The parent and the children with cascading persist or do you persist each entity separately. This would clarify a lot of things.

Comment: Freakyuser, I thought is was obvious that my problem was having duplicates from my query.

Comment: It is persisted in the DB with the Child having a foreign key pointing to the Parent table, using the Parent's primary key.

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of the duplicates by using the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent FROM Parent parent JOIN parent.child child WHERE ...
```

EDIT: The `DISTINCT` keyword is used to remoe duplicates from query results regardless of teh reason for the existence of these duplicates. Sometimes the reason is duplicate DB entries. But more often, duplicates are the consequence of `JOIN` statements, so your use case is completely legitimate.

However, you could avoid explicit joins and the `DISTINCT` keyword by making the relation bidirectional. Then you can use implicit joins through navigation:

```
SELECT parent FROM Parent parent WHERE parent.children...
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I thought the DISTINCT keyword was to eliminate duplicates present in the DB, not duplicates generated by the query.

Comment: @user2343647 - you're welcome :) I have added some more info  - please see the edit