# Spring Data + View with Union return duplicate rows

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa, duplicates, union

i'm using Spring Boot 2.4.2 and Data module for JPA implementation.

Now, i'm using an Oracle View, mapped by this JPA Entity:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "ORDER_EXPORT_V")
@ToString
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class OrderExportView implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4417678438840201704L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private Long id;
....
```

The view uses an UNION which allows me to obtain two different attributes of the same parent entity, so for one same parent entity (A) with this UNION I get the attribute B in row 1 and attribute C in row 2: this means that the rows will be different from each other.

If I run the query with an Oracle client, I get the result set I expect: same parent entity with 2 different rows containing the different attributes.
Now the issue: when I run the query with Spring Data (JPA), I get the wrong result set: two lines but duplicate.

In debug, I check the query that perform Spring Data and it's correct; if I run the same query, the result set is correct, but from Java/Spring Data not. Why??

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Looks like a problem with one-to-many:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341408/jpa-hibernate-duplicate-records

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I was wrong in the ID field.

The two rows have the same parent id, which is not good for JPA, which instead expects a unique value for each line.
So, now I introduced a UUID field into the view:

```
sys_guid() AS uuid
```

and in JPA Entity:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "UUID", nullable = false)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private UUID uuid;

@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
```

and now everything works fine, as the new field has a unique value for each row.